# Best (light-weight) web-proxying software to use for my particular setup?

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, haproxy

(Sorry for the dashes in my URLs for examples; I do not have enough "reputation points" to post multiple link, even though they're fake links).

I have a back-end server running Apache at 1.2.3.4 that hosts multiple websites, each referenced by a "virtual host". I wish to keep that server's identity protected so I wish to setup multiple proxies that will serve content on its behalf, tunneling traffic back and forth from the requesting client to the server.

I have looked into "haproxy" and it seems like it may suit my needs - however, I'm not sure how it works with virtual hosts. I need to be able to feed the user a website referenced by a virtual host when accessed from haproxy (or, whatever other software would suit this). For instance if the back-end site is www-site-com and is running at 1.2.3.4, and the proxy front-end is at www-anothersite-com at 2.3.4.5, then all requests to www-anothersite-com/ needs to fetch the contents of www-site-com from 1.2.3.4 and pass it along.

Is this possible with haproxy? And if so, how? Is it possible to instruct haproxy to perhaps also do this on a directory level - accessing www-anothersite-com/site1/ would fetch www-domain1-com from the backend, while www-anothersite-com/site2/ would fetch www-domain2-com from the backend? (and, of course, translate all of its respective paths for instance www-anothersite-com/site2/images/hello.jpg would fetch www-domain2-com/images/hello.jpg from the backend).

If haproxy isn't the software for this, what suggestions do you all have? I haven't much experience with any type of proxying software so I am open to suggestions.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You can format URL's as `code` by unclosing them in back-ticks and then they won't be expanded as active hyperlinks.   - Also: In your questions please refrain from using random domain names and use either your *own domain* or one of the [RFC 6761](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6761#section-6.5) reserved domain names such as  `example.com`, `example.org`  or similar . Please refer to [this Q&A](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/37681) for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate in your questions.

Comment: So your planned setup looks like: Client <> Frontend 2.3.4.5 <> HAProxy <> Backend 1.2.3.4? To me this looks quite complicated, but I'm also not really sure about what you want to achieve. Anyway, besides this: Yes, HAProxy is capable of doing this, via [ACLs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#7). [Here](https://seanmcgary.com/posts/haproxy---route-by-domain-name) is a tutorial showing you how to use these.